# Speeding up LaTeX compilation via .bat-file

Tags: compiling

last time I created large LaTeX files, I found a webpage that explained the use of .bat-files to execute the compilation which worked perfectly! Neither can I find this page anymore, nor do I remember every detail for the creation of the file. Maybe you guys can help me how to structure the .bat file (or what to consider) or know the page where to find more information.
I know, I could speed up using draft mode, resizing pictures, externalizing preamble etc. but in the end my dissertation should be hq so this will only help on the short run.

For my last document, the preamble compilation was following:

```
pdftex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx tex_file
```

for the whole document I used:

```
pdflatex tex_file
biber tex_file
pdflatex tex_file
pdflatex tex_file
```

Best,
an ordinary LaTeX user

Comment: a bat file (like a linux shell script) just runs commands you could run directly it doesn't in itself speed or slow anything.  However the `mylatexformat` line you show is using the `mylatexformat` package to save your document preamble into a custom format you can follow the steps in `texdoc mylatexformat` or online at https://texdoc.org/serve/mylatexformat/0

Comment: note that if you are using the bat file you show every run that is much slower than necessary, it's running latex three times and biber, so almost always after an edit you just need to run latex once, so this is three or four times faster than running your batch file.

Comment: For batch file documentation... I think running `help cmd` and `help` in cmd works somewhat well. I think Microsoft help pages *might* have more

Comment: Thank you, this already helps me a lot. I should check mylatexformat again! I used the command outside of TeXstudio, so it runs faster and the editor doesn't crash what it did becaus my file was too large.

Comment: Note that `mylatexformat` shouldn't be used with LuaLaTeX (at least not naively). Just in case you didn't know and want to change engines sometime in the future.